# Can't load library R Studio

Tags: r

I am trying to install the ggmap library:

```
 install.packages("ggmap")
 library(ggmap)
```

This is what I get though:

```
Installing package into ‘my path’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ggmap_2.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4563151 bytes (4.4 MB)
downloaded 4.4 MB

package ‘ggmap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    my path
> library(ggmap)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggmap’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘maps’
```

It used to work, then I don't know what happened and it stopped working. Any ideas ? I tried removing the package then installing it again but it still doesn't work

Comment: Looks like you need `maps` try `install.packages("maps")` and then do the `ggmap` isntallataion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time when installing packages, try this:

```
install.packages("ggmap",dependencies=TRUE)
library(ggmap)
```

The extra argument will make sure all the necessary dependencies are also installed.